# How can I throw an exception from XSLT?

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I want to throw an exception if one tag doesn't contain an attribute.

Comment: Show code, show some effort, not just what you want.

Comment: Does this help? http://weblogs.asp.net/george_v_reilly/archive/2006/03/01/439402.aspx

Comment: -1 and voting to close. This isn't a considered or constructive question, and it will take a lot of work to discover what is needed. Serial upvoter please stop

Comment: you cant but can achieve the same what you are trying to do in catch by some other ways. elaborate your question

Comment: @Borodin, Why do you think this isn't a constructive question? This question is based on a solid use-case and has a good solution in XSLT 1.0, XSLT 2.0, XSLT 3.0 and XPath 2.0 and 3.0. It may be a good idea to reverse your downvote.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev it's not at all clear how the OP is trying to throw an exception. For one thing, the question is tagged [java], so I would have expected him to be asking about throwing a Java exception from Java-XSLT library code. The accepted answer has nothing to do with Java, though, so that's probably not right.

Comment: @LordTorgamus, The OP *doesn't know* how to raise an exception and this is why he is asking this question -- why do you expect this to be clear to the OP? Java is not the only tag for this question, and XSLT is also a tag -- therefore, the OP was asking how an exception can be thrown from XSLT -- Petr Kozelka gave him exactly the answer that the OP needed. Once again: taking all this into account, why did you decide to vote for closing this question? The question is well-defined and clear -- it makes perfect sense and the answers are valuable to many people. Please, vote to re-open.Pls. reopen

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**In addition to the correct answer of using `<xsl:message terminate="yes"/>`:**

1. In XSLT 3.0 one can use the new instructions `<xsl:try ...>` and `<xsl:catch ...>`: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#try-catch
2. In XSLT 2.0 one can also use the standart XPath function **[`error()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-error)** to terminate the processing.

**Here is an example of using `xsl:try` and `xsl:catch`**:

```
<xsl:result-document href="out.xml">
  <xsl:variable name="result">
    <xsl:call-template name="construct-output"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:try>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$result" validation="strict"/>
    <xsl:catch>
      <xsl:message>Warning: validation of result document failed:
          Error code: <xsl:value-of select="$err:code"/>
          Reason: <xsl:value-of select="$err:description"/>
      </xsl:message>
      <xsl:sequence select="$result"/>
    </xsl:catch>
  </xsl:try>
</xsl:result-document>
```

Answer (score 35):

Use [`xsl:message` with `terminate="yes"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#message) to achieve effect similar to throwing an exception:

```
<xsl:if test="(your condition)">
   <xsl:message terminate="yes">ERROR: Missing attribute XYZ under
      <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/> !</xsl:message>
</xsl:if>
```

This causes the message to be sent to STDERR and terminate processing.

BTW. this is heavily used in [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/) validation.

Answer (score 2):

XSLT isn't meant for validation! it is meant for transformation .. (well XSLT stands for EXtensible Stylesheet Language Transformation)

If you want to validate hierarchy (that is your requirement) and validate the data .. then go for XSD! Extensible Schema Definition..

here is a link reference to [learn XSD](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/default.asp)

XML has to be validated against the XSD by the host code (C#, Java etc) The validation returns set of results. Success or fail with validation errors (if exist)..

Comment: InfantProgrammer'Aravind, XSLT has been used for validation even in version 1.0. Schematron is based on XSLT. In XSLT 2.0 there are extensive XSD validation capabilities, which any XSLT 2.0 SA (Schema-Aware) XSLT processor implements.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, yes :) I had kind of forgotten it .. now I recall :) thanks..

Comment: "XSLT isn't meant for validation! it is meant for transformation" and then you get a comment that clearly states that it can be used for validation and has been used for it! so your answer is partly wrong.

Comment: @Petoj, Of course, your statement isn't true -- read the xsl-list (recent threads) and Michael Kay's book and you'll see the light.